# How to limit the number of displayed kivy spinner items

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am am currently using the spinner widget of kivy and i would like to know if there is a way to limit the number of items the spinner shows and scroll to see the rest.
For example, i am using a spinner to display all the months, so when i click the spinner, the list reaches the bottom of the window. I would like to see maybe like 5-6 options and scroll to see the rest of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`dropdown_cls.max_size`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html#kivy.uix.spinner.Spinner.dropdown_cls) property to specify the maximum height of the drop-down list:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner


max = 10
spinner = Spinner(
    text='Values',
    values=(str(n) for n in range(1, 20)),
    size_hint=(None, None),
    size=(100, 44),
    pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.9})

spinner.dropdown_cls.max_height = spinner.height* max + max * 4

runTouchApp(spinner)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect solution for my problem, thank you !