# Kivy spinner, limit the number of displayed items

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to make a spinner menu that has a maximum drop down height, I have tried to implement the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000831/how-to-limit-the-number-of-displayed-kivy-spinner-items) question, but can't get it to work. My code structure is part of a larger program, so if I can avoid reformatting it would be preferred.

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen , ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class SimpleKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Kivy File:

```
ScreenManager:

    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Change Screen"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, 'top': 0.7}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                on_release: 
                    root.current = 'screen2'

    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'
        FloatLayout:
            Spinner:
                id: spinner
                text: 'Select Number'
                values: ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20')
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, 'top': 0.7}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `on_enter` event of the `Screen` class as follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    def limit_spinner(self, *args):
        max = 5  # max number of Buttons to display in the Spinner DropDown
        self.spinner.dropdown_cls.max_height =  max * dp(48)  # dp(48) is the size of each Button in the DropDown (from style.kv)


theRoot = Builder.load_string('''
ScreenManager:

    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Change Screen"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, 'top': 0.7}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                on_release: 
                    root.current = 'screen2'

    Screen2:
        spinner: spinner
        name: 'screen2'
        on_enter: self.limit_spinner()
        FloatLayout:
            Spinner:
                id: spinner
                text: 'Select Number'
                values: ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20')
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, 'top': 0.7}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
''')


class SimpleKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return theRoot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

This uses some information from the question you referenced. Also uses a `spinner` `ObjectProperty` in `Screen2`. The `on_enter` event triggers the `limit_spinner()` method.